# how do i deactivate these random zooms while rotating an object?

Tags: customization

i use the logitech master mx3 and i rotate an object by holding the middle mousebutton (mousewheel) and move my mouse. but somehow there are random zooms while i press the mousewheel to rotate the object and its like it zooms in randomly just a little bit. like every two or three times i press the mousewheel it des this and i don't want to change the buttons to rotate it, i want to keep it at m middle mousebutton … does anyone know why or how i can deactivate it?

Comment: Recording the behavior using a screen recording tool like ShareX could help. Also you could turn off Logitech Gaming Software to see if it's perhaps some shortcut-like functionality that causes this.

Comment: How can i share a video?

Comment: For example using https://streamable.com/

Comment: https://streamable.com/hjhjns there is a video,i hope you can understand in this video what my problem is...

Comment: To me it looks like if every time you press/release the mousewheel, you also scroll the wheel by a single step.

Comment: I think an Autohotkey macro could be written to block mouse wheel scrolling if it was just held, and reverse mouse wheel scrolling if it's pressed immediately after.